# в чдачах и в нечдачах

Tags: правописание, орфография

А есть на это<strike>й</strike>**м** плакате несколько слов,  незнакомые мне, и которых не найдётся <strike>б</strike> **в** словарях.
Суть

- в чдачах и в нечдачах
  (разве это просто опечатка? имелось слово "удачах" ввиду?)
- чничтожим
  (разве это точно таже опечатка?)
- также слово "нащего" написано чуть по-другому. Как мне кажется, обычно через букву Ш пишется а здесь, через Щ.

[image]

Comment: Текст тоже не совсем корректен. "Борющихся с ними" можно понять как "fighting against them", хотя очевидно, что у плаката противоположный смысл.

Comment: funny that you made a similar mistake as the authors of the poster, having used **б** instead of **в** in **найдётся б словарях**, or was it deliberate to illustrate the point in a roundabout way? ))))

Comment: в данном контексте надо писать раздельно :-) `точно та же опечатка` /// точнее говоря, путаница бывает в парах "тоже / то же" и "также / так же", а слова "таже" просто не существует :-D

Comment: Интересно, много у вас таких старых плакатов?

Comment: @Arioch нет. Я его нашёл на википедии.

Comment: I am not sure it is an authentic WWII poster. It might be from some Hollywood movie, for example.

Comment: До чего прекрасный плакат! Чничтожим нащеrо враrа!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Конечно это ошибки.

и БОРЮЩИХС**А** (со [старомосковским](https://blog.accent-center.ru/2016/04/26/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE/) [акцентом](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=WEcyDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT33&lpg=PT33&dq=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5+%D0%A1%D0%90+%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%A1%D0%AF&source=bl&ots=zxDWbE764h&sig=yTgFsL5fjdvXP0RKY1S1iVykxms&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiawOWt3cTbAhVDFywKHbbUA2AQ6AEIQjAD#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D0%A1%D0%90%20%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%A1%D0%AF&f=false)) впридачу, в сильно двусмысленной фразе `борющихся с ними`.

Покольку плакат, насколько можно судить по тексту, выпущен в Британии, орфографические ошибки вызваны, очевидно, плохим знакомством с русским алфавитом и, видимо языком тоже, и потому неумением различать похожие по начертанию буквы.

Во избежание двусмысленности выражение `борющихся с ними` следовало бы перефразировать, например, как `борющихся ВМЕСТЕ с ними` или `борющихся с ними ПЛЕЧОМ К ПЛЕЧУ`.

Comment: `в сильно двусмысленной фразе борющихся с ними` - Это скорее всего из протоевропейского. Ведь в английском ровно та же двусмусленность - "fighting with cat" : https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/97983 / https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236771 / https://www.italki.com/question/108074

Comment: @Arioch да, согласен

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка имхо, "плечом к плечу" сказать нельзя, ведь британцы атаковали Третий Рейх с запада, а советские воины - с востока.

Comment: @user31264 ради красного словца всё годится

Answer (score 4):

Ошибки.  Автор плаката отвратительно знает русский язык.  К тому, что написал Баян Купи-ка, добавлю, что пропущены все знаки препинания, а "Советский Союз" надо писать с заглавных букв, и предложения тоже надо начинать с заглавной буквы.

Должно быть:

> Привет геройским воинам Советского Союза от британских союзников,
>   борющихся вместе с ними!
>
> Мы всегда с вами в удачах и неудачах. Вместе добьем, разгромим,
>   уничтожим нашего врага!

PS: я заметил, что буква г везде написана как латинская буква r. Bозможно, у художника просто не было трафаретов некоторых русских букв. Он заменил их похожими по очертаниям.  Кроме того, возможно, что это вообще нe аутентичный плакат, а, например, фрагмент кадра из фильма.

Comment: учитывая то, что на плакате текст полностью набран прописными буквами (капслоком) актуальность выделения заглавных букв пропадает, хотя они там предприняли попытку выделить их

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка тогда им нельзя было делать некоторые буквы больше соседних ("Привет Геройским Воинам").

Answer (score -3):

Насчет *ЧДАЧАХ* и *НЕЧДАЧАХ* - в старых печатных машинках СССР буквы **У** и **Ч** обозначались одним символом **Ч**. Вероятно, автор плаката использовал начертание символов с клавиатуры.

Comment: я не уверен ...

Comment: Раскладка клавиатуры на [советских](http://mytypewriter.ru/images/cms/data/02d314422ced8ec8ebb89be933ad793f_d3858e5c729ce1fd2dd5558f048469f4.jpg) и [дореволюционных](https://pics.meshok.net/pics2/32929329.jpg) печатных машинках почти соответствует современной компьютерной. Буквы "у" и "ч" имели отдельные клавиши и литеры.

Comment: возможно бывали случаи, когда они использовались друг вместо друга при выходе из строя одной из них, но очевидно это было исключением, а не правилом